# Removing Timestamp from date (text format)

Tags: excel, vba, datetime

I have an Excel macro getting 1000+ records from database.

The dates in the data are fetched with timestamp and is in text format. I need to format the dates in DD-MON-YYYY format.

Input:
2016-04-03 00:00:00

Output:
03-Apr-2016

I tried:

1. Casting all the date columns to date in the DB query - The macro keeps running for forever and excel stops responding.
2. `TRUNC(TO_DATE('PROJECT_START_DATE'),'YEAR')` in query - Throws error
3. `INT(Cell)` or `DateTime(Cell)` in excel - Throws error

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. Could you attach your input?

Comment: So why not try handling this at the data source, as is best? Is this a SQL database you're getting your information from?  If it is, then just sub-string the left hand side of the date field. The right tool for the right job...

Comment: How are you "fetching the date"?  That is probably the most efficient method of handling this problem -- whether in the code that extracts the date from the DB, or in the code that imports it into Excel (if the data from the DB format is not under your control).  Excel can sometimes do unwanted processing on date/time stamps which is best avoided by processing the information before.

Comment: I have 24 date columns and when applying sub string in the query it is taking forever for the macro to run. Also some of these records are in date format and others in VARCHAR in the DB. I do not have access to this DB or a tool to view the table structure as of now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really get the date in text format like `2016-04-03 00:00:00` as in your post then you could use the following function to get a date without a timestamp

```
Function cvtDt(inp As String) As Date
' inp is a string like 2016-04-03 00:00:00
    On Error GoTo EH

    cvtDt = CDate(Left(inp, 10))
    Exit Function

EH:
    cvtDt = 0
End Function
```

The following sub then writes your example data to a cell in a sheet with the format you mentioned in your post.

```
Sub OutToXL()

    Dim val As Date
    val = cvtDt("2016-04-03 00:00:00")

    With Range("A1")
        .NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy"
        .Value2 = val
    End With

End Sub
```

`INT` should also work unless you have white spaces at the end of your string. In this case it will throw an error.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, I am new to VBA, What does CDate() do ?

Comment: CDate is a type [conversion function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions)

Comment: I need to edit an existing VBA Code for this. I need to do this after the code has populated all the cells. Can you guide me on how to go about that ?

Comment: Sure. Thanks @Storax